# How to pattern match a list of APIs calls to their API Pattern (or group)?

Tags: regex, postgresql, splunk

I need to do an **analysis on API calls** using logs, like **avg, min, max response time**.

**Background**

I am using **splunk**, so these API calls get logged in my ILB logs which then I am able to capture and export to a **CSV** using Splunk. So, for an API `/data/user/{id}`, I might have multiple calls along with their response times, Ex :

```
/data/users/1443 | 0.5 sec
/data/users/2232 | 0.2 sec
```

**Challenge :**

What would be an easy and optimal way, if let's say the sheet which has these API calls hits data has 10 million records, and I have a list of API patterns, let's say 3000 API Patterns (Ex: `/data/user/{id}/address`, `/data/user/{id}/xyz/{another_id}`)

*Note: **{id}** could be alphanumeric in some APIs.*

**Current Approach**

I load this CSV sheet into a table (call it the `raw data table`, with details of every single API hit on ILB along with it's response time) in a **PostgresSQL db**, and then have a `master table` with fixed list of APIs and a column in which I replace the path variables with regex patterns, and then I join the master table with the raw data table using a regex based join, and calculate avg, min, max response_time etc.

However, due to using regex join, ***the query is taking like 5-6 hrs to run***.

Could I do something better?

*Note: **Sample CSV** with few rows of raw data : https://pastebin.com/Nx0Hnc9u*

```
proxy                              method   request_time
/data/users/{id}                    POST    0.046
/server/healthcheck/check/up        GET     0.001
/data/commons/people/multi_upsert   POST    0.141
/store/org/manufacturing/multi_read POST    0.363
/data/users/{id}/homepage/{name}    POST    0.084
/data/view/{name}/pagecount         PUT     0.043

Category 1 (path variable only at the end) :
/data/users/{id}                    POST    0.046

Category 2 (1 or more path variables only in the middle) :
/data/view/{name}/pagecount                         PUT     0.043
/data/view/{name}/details/{type}/pagecount          PUT     0.043

Category 3 (1 or more path variables only in the middle and also at the end) :
/data/users/{id}/homepage/{name}    POST    0.084
/data/users/{id}/homepage/{type}/details/{name} POST    0.084
```

Comment: So all of the records are in a single csv? ... can you pastebin (or similar) a chunk of the csv? Also, you say Avg, Min, Max do you want it for each IP/User ID, or just overall?

Comment: @Nefariis: Just added the CSV with few rows of sample data.

Comment: Why not do your "grouping" in Splunk prior to export? Bet it'd be a *lot* more efficient.

Comment: Define how you want to "group" your events: are you grouping based on `{id}`? The path? Part of the path? Something else? In Splunk, I can envision a couple ways to get towards (or to exactly) what you're looking for ... but you gotta define your terms :)

Comment: if I am understanding his question correctly, he would like the calls grouped, not the individual ID's. So all `/data/users/{id}` together, not `/data/users/2345` and `/data/users/3456` separately, which is what Splunk's "Group By" feature would do. Which is why he is going line by line with regex.

Comment: @Nefariis - maybe that's right? `rex`'ing-out what he wants is going to be pretty fast in Splunk, though :)

Comment: @warren, yeah I have no idea what he is looking for - if he has a CSV though, im inclined just to write a script (python, etc) to get the information.

Comment: @Nefariis if it *has* to be CSV ... I concur. However, if *I* happen to be right (a big "if" until OP clarifies) ... doing it in Splunk'll be simpler :)

Comment: @Nefariis yes you are right I would like the calls to be grouped by the pattern like `/data/user/{id}` for all values of `{id}`, ex: `/data/users/2345`, `/data/users/3456`, `/data/users/442` etc

Comment: @warren: **yes I can rex it in splunk**, and I tried it, but the issue is there are around **1200 distinct API patterns**, and if I add **1200 distinct rex match and replace lines** in the **Splunk query** it becomes **too heavy for splunk to parse**

Comment: I am adding lines like these for each API pattern to the Splunk Query : 
`|rex mode=sed field=uri_path "s/\/api\/data\/users\/([^\/]+)$/\/api\/data\/users\/{id}/g"`

Comment: You might need to take a step back and redesign your API logging to accommodate what you are looking for. Your problem set is incredibly interesting, but the idea that you need to run 1200 regex calls against each line means that your design might be flawed... Instead of logging each ID with the call, could you just log the call? That right there would eliminate the need for regex altogether, then you could just do a "Splunk Group By" query. Another option is an api analytics library that automatically reports and keeps track of every call made, then you could auto group them into services.

Comment: @user2533630 - I sincerely doubt you need to build regular expressions for "1200 distinct API patterns". I'd *strongly* suspect you can do it *far* more simply ...unless you really do have an incredibly degenerate API universe you're looking at :)

Comment: what rule(s) define your "name" or "user" components in your URIs?

Comment: @Nefariis : I understand your point, and I agree with it, the design should be improved. Unfortunately though, I am currently stuck with this design and need to have a workaround for the time being.

Comment: @warren : I think you are right, it could be improved, I could have one regex for all those APIs which maybe have `atleast 1 number+ n chars`, or `only numbers` for the `{id}` values and directly replace them with {id}. The challenge would be for those APIs in which the path variable like `{id} has string alone`. For that I would need to know which part of the whole API/URI is static and which needs to be replace. For that I am guessing I would have to use a static pattern? What do you say?

Comment: @user2533630 - do *all* of the API formats you have match what you shared in the clipped sample? Do they *always* follow the format does "`{id}`" you mentioned? This is *probably* something that can be rex'd out simpler than you're thinking about (though, it may be more difficult than it sounds)

Comment: @warren: what I shared in the paste bin are just samples, that is not the exhaustive list. In total there are about 3000 such patterns/URIs/APIs. But they can be categorized into 3 types, those that have a path variable only at the end, those that have 1 or more path variables only in the middle, and those that have 1 or more path variables in the middle as well as in the end. Note: there are **no arguments after the API** i.e. like /data/view/{name}/pagecount`?age=x`. There will be just the URI part.

Comment: @user2533630 - please supply examples of each of the three categories. In the pastebin (which I edited into the question so it was easily viewable) you already provided, you don't *seem* to have examples of each type of API endpoint

Comment: @warren: Sure, I have updated the examples of each category in the question.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - can we open the question? I have a possible solution with the information given.

Comment: @Nefariis: The question is open now, can you please post your answer?

Answer (score 1):

So how I choose to implement the solution was through python, and I did that for a few reasons.

1. Generally python is fast - you are performing numerous regex searches on every line, python has features like pop, break, and comprehensive if/else statements that can further speed things along. (I believe I'm using pop pretty effectively to continually make the list smaller on every regex iteration)
2. Limited Production data - it was really really hard to recreate your environment. Whatever answer I might have came up with, I wouldn't have been able to test it and I couldn't guarantee that it would be any faster or that it would have even of worked.
3. You already have a CSV - that's honestly 90% of it right there, putting that CSV back into splunk just seems like extra steps.
4. This can be scaled accordingly to anything you want - I attempted to make this as intuitive as possible and only used base libraries. Update the regex.txt, and the CSV,  and Go

now for the meat and potatoes -

I have three files, `regex.txt`, `api_calls.csv`, `api_reg.py` (make sure they are all in the same folder).

`api_calls.csv` - (This is the CSV output of your calls, notice the headers are still there)

```
proxy,method,request_time
/request_time/data/users/3456,POST,0.056
/server/healthcheck/check/up,GET,0.012
/data/commons/people/multi_upsert,POST,0.131
/store/org/manufacturing/multi_read,POST,0.463
/data/users/45645/homepage/fghrt,POST,0.074
/request_time/data/users/5643,POST,0.026
/data/view/fgnfrt/pagecount,PUT,0.034
/server/healthcheck/check/up,GET,0.016
/data/commons/people/multi_upsert,POST,0.135
/store/org/manufacturing/multi_read,POST,0.163
/data/users/45678/homepage/fgbfgn,POST,0.062
/data/view/dfg/pagecount,PUT,0.073
/request_time/data/users/7567,POST,0.026
/server/healthcheck/check/up,GET,0.011
/data/commons/people/multi_upsert,POST,0.121
/store/org/manufacturing/multi_read,POST,0.323
/data/users/64564/homepage/fghfgh,POST,0.054
/data/view/hrthe/pagecount,PUT,0.093
/server/healthcheck/check/up,GET,0.021
/data/commons/people/multi_upsert,POST,0.041
/request_time/data/users/3456,POST,0.048
/store/org/manufacturing/multi_read,POST,0.323
/data/users/56756/homepage/hrthr,POST,0.054
/data/view/bdfbdr/pagecount,PUT,0.103
```

`regex.txt` - (Here is where you put your desired regexes)

```
\/data\/users\/.*\/homepage\/.*
\/server\/healthcheck\/check\/up
\/data\/commons\/people\/multi_upsert
\/store\/org\/manufacturing\/multi_read
\/data\/view\/.*\/pagecount
\/request_time\/data\/users\/.*
```

`api_reg.py` - (Here is the python script)

```
import re
import csv
import json

csvDoc = list(csv.DictReader(open("api_calls.csv").readlines()))
regexes = open("regex.txt").readlines()
apis = {}

for regex in regexes:
    regex = regex.strip()
    prettyReg = regex.replace("\\", "")

    for line in reversed(csvDoc):

        if re.findall(regex, line['proxy']):
            csvDoc.pop(csvDoc.index(line))
            time = float(line['request_time'])

            if prettyReg not in apis:
                apis[prettyReg] = {"min": float("inf"), "max": float("-inf"), "avg": 0.0, "total": 0.0, "count": 0}

            apis[prettyReg]['total'] += time
            apis[prettyReg]['count'] += 1
            apis[prettyReg]['avg'] = apis[prettyReg]['total'] / apis[prettyReg]['count']
            if time < apis[prettyReg]['min']: apis[prettyReg]['min'] = time
            if time > apis[prettyReg]['max']: apis[prettyReg]['max'] = time


with open("output.txt", "w+") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(apis, indent=4))
```

output.txt - (this is what the above script generates given the api_calls.csv and regex.txt)

```
{
    "/data/users/.*/homepage/.*": {
        "min": 0.054,
        "max": 0.074,
        "avg": 0.061,
        "total": 0.244,
        "count": 4
    },
    "/server/healthcheck/check/up": {
        "min": 0.011,
        "max": 0.021,
        "avg": 0.015,
        "total": 0.06,
        "count": 4
    },
    "/data/commons/people/multi_upsert": {
        "min": 0.041,
        "max": 0.135,
        "avg": 0.10700000000000001,
        "total": 0.42800000000000005,
        "count": 4
    },
    "/store/org/manufacturing/multi_read": {
        "min": 0.163,
        "max": 0.463,
        "avg": 0.318,
        "total": 1.272,
        "count": 4
    },
    "/data/view/.*/pagecount": {
        "min": 0.034,
        "max": 0.103,
        "avg": 0.07575000000000001,
        "total": 0.30300000000000005,
        "count": 4
    },
    "/request_time/data/users/.*": {
        "min": 0.026,
        "max": 0.056,
        "avg": 0.039,
        "total": 0.156,
        "count": 4
    }
}
```

Sorry I couldn't come up with something using splunk, but I guarantee this method will not take 5-6 hours to run.

If you do not have python on your computer, download Python (currently 3.9.6) and I recommend using the IDE Pycharm from IDEA - they are the best/easiest plug and play everything to get going.

If you have questions or would like something added/changed, feel free to post in the comments and I will update.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Nefariis, I will try it out and let you know. One question, If I need to find percentile values of the response time, like percentile95th response time or percentile99 etc, do you think I could do that with your solution? I am not very used to python, I am sorry.

Comment: Yup I could add that for you - but, first check to make sure that the solution in general will work for you. I want to make sure it will fit your needs before I go to far down a rabbit hole. If you need any help setting it or the regex's up, let me know.